# Build dynamic COND clauses in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lisp-macros

I wonder if it is possible to dynamically build COND clauses from a loop like (pseudo code):

```
(defvar current-state 1)

(defmacro mymacro ()
  (cond
    `(loop (state . callback) in possible-states
      do ((eq current-state ,state)
          (funcall ,callback)))))
```

The LOOP would build the clauses from a list and generate something like:

```
(cond
  ((eq current-state 1)
   (funcall func-1))
  ((eq current-state 2)
   (funcall func-2))
  ((eq current-state 3)
   (funcall func-3)))
```

Comment: to build a list, isn't it what [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) is there for? to splice a list in place, `,@` can be used.

Comment: If your state is a number and all states are continugous, maybe use a vector of callbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are expanded at compile time, so your `possible-states` variable has to be a compile-time constant. If this is not the case (or if you are not absolutely clear on what I mean above), you should ***not*** use a macro here.

Use a function instead:

```
(funcall (cdr (find current-state possible-states :key #'car :test #'eq)))
```

or

```
(funcall (cdr (assoc current-state possible-states :test #'eq)))
```

or, better yet, make your `possible-states` a [hash
table](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/18_.htm) rather than an [association
list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_assocc.htm):

```
(funcall (gethash current-state possible-states))
```

However, if your `possible-states` ***is*** a compile time constant, you
can, indeed, use a macro, except that you probably want to use
[`case`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_case_.htm) instead of
[`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm):

```
(defmacro state-dispatch (state)
  `(case ,state
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (cell)
                 `((,(car cell)) (,(cdr cell))))
               possible-states)))
(defparameter possible-states '((1 . foo) (2 . bar)))
(macroexpand-1 '(state-dispatch mystate))
==> (CASE MYSTATE ((1) (FOO)) ((2) (BAR))) ; T
```

Note that from the *speed* point of view, the [`gethash`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gethas.htm) version is probably identical to the macro version (at the very least it is not slower).